# Display multiplication table from 2 to 12 in C#, WPF format

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to write a program that asks the user for a number from 2 to 12, and then displays a multiplication table with answers in the format below:

User enters: 6
Output:

```
     2    3    4    5    6 

2    4    6    8    10   12

3    6    9    12   15   18

4    8    12   16   20   24

5    10   15   20   25   30

6    12   18   24   30   36
```

I cannot get, neither the top horizontal row (2, 3, 4, 5, 6), nor the left column (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) to display on the WPF application screen, and I also need to get the vertical tab right, so all the numbers are equally spaced horizontally and vertically. My current code looks like this:

```
    int inputNumber;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnYes.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void calculateTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inputNumber = int.Parse(number.Text);
        if (inputNumber < 2 || inputNumber > 12)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter values between 2 and 12");
            number.Clear();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= inputNumber; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= inputNumber; j++)
            {
                displayValues.Text += (i * j).ToString() + '\t';
            }
            displayValues.Text += '\n';
        }
        calculateTable.IsEnabled = false;
        btnYes.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void btnYes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        number.Clear();
        number.Focus();
        displayValues.Text = String.Empty;
        btnYes.IsEnabled = false;
        calculateTable.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void btnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your XAML code?

Comment: See my answer, if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you forgot to print out the first number of the `ì` -loop iteration. For the linebreak you can also use `Environment.NewLine`
I used here a `TextBox` for the display.

Try this:

```
int inputNumber = 6;

for (int i = 2; i <= inputNumber; i++)
{
    textBox.Text += i.ToString() + '\t';


    for (int j = 2; j <= inputNumber; j++)
    {
        textBox.Text += (i * j).ToString() + '\t';
    }
    textBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
}
```

The result looks the following:

[image]

And for `inputNumber = 12` like this:

[image]

hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Ok after you edit I understand you a little better.

To get the first line you need only to include an enumeration from 2 to the `inputNumber` with a leading whitespace `" "`. For the vertical alignment you could cheat a little and take 3 `NewLine`s, that would be spacially the same as a tab.

here is an example code:

```
int inputNumber = 6;

textBox.Text += " \t" + String.Join("\t", Enumerable.Range(2, inputNumber-1)) + new string('\n', 3);

for (int i = 2; i <= inputNumber; i++)
{
    textBox.Text += i.ToString() + '\t';

    for (int j = 2; j <= inputNumber; j++)
    {
        textBox.Text += (i * j).ToString() + '\t';
    }
    textBox.Text += new string('\n', 3);
}
```

The result should look now like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the hint, but I'm still not getting the numbers from, e.g. 2 to 6 on the top row and the numbers are not evenly distributed vertically either (not same spacing between numbers as in the horizontal direction).

Comment: @Altor Ah now I get you better. The first lineis actually just an enumeration with a leading `" "`, and with the vertical alignment you can cheat a little ;) check out my edit.

Comment: @Altor You are welcome. Glad I could be of help. Best way of thanking at StackOverflow is to mark the response that helped you as answer :-)

Comment: Hi Mong Zhu, sorry I'm new to StackOverflow therefore don't know how to mark the response that helped me solve my issue. However, if you explain me how to do it, I'll gladly do it.

Comment: @Altor beneath the triangles for voting up and down there is a grey check mark. Click on it and it will turn green. This [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) might help you if you are new to StackOverflow and the [helping center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is also a good start. It has a lot of usefull information. Have fun and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and meaningful approach :

Use `UniformGrid` as `<UniformGrid x:Name="UG" Columns="10"/>`, code :

```
    int from = 2, to = 15;
    for (int i = from; i <= to; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; ++j)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() { Text = (i * j).ToString() };
            UG.Children.Add(tb);
        }
    }
```

There are other approaches :

1. Create a `StackPanel` with `Orientation = Horizontal` for every table. Use `TextBlock` for every digit.
2. Create a `Grid` with 10 columns. Your Columns are fixed, but Rows vary. So, you can create needed Rows, and show every digit in relevant Column. Use [RowDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition(v=vs.110).aspx), [Grid.SetRow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589026(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Grid.SetColumn()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589023(v=vs.110).aspx) .
3. Use a `DataGrid` and make it `ReadOnly`. Create your list, and simple assign it as `DataGrid.ItemsSource`. You can format the `DataGrid` to hide various lines etc.

Comment: Thanks Anjum, but I'm not exactly getting the result I want.

Comment: @Altor Create an image with sample output and exact requirement

Answer (score 0):

The answer I need to get from my program should be in the following format:
[Multiplication Tables from 2 to 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO5Re.jpg)

I'm getting the left most column (2 to 8) and the results, but not the the top row (2 to 8) and the vertical spacing between the numbers. All numbers have to be evenly spaced/distributed in the grid.